# Select2 with bootstrap timepicker for multiple show times

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker, jquery-select2

I have a form with event start date and start time fields separately. The event start time(s) can be more than one. For example, for a given event date there may be multiple show times for which I need to enter all the show times. I am considering to use select2 plugin with multi select option to enter all the show times as tags in single field. I am already using bootstrap timepicker to select time. How can I integrate this time picker along with select2 plugin to accomplish my requirement.

[image]